# Meaning of "like a mountain breaking lather"

Tags: meaning

"...And there is another smell, too, yonder beneath the fresh pine and cigarette smoke—hay, blood, something big and wild and musky. **An old reek, like a mountain breaking lather.** Once you've gotten a whiff of it, you never forget the smell of an elephant."
source: Brooke Bolander. *The Only Harmless Great Thing*

The smell in the first sentence refers to the smell of an elephant. 
Could you please explain the sentence in bold? Here, is reek used in the sense of "smell"? Break lather means sweat, I guess, here does the mountain sweat and emit a smell, figuratively of course? Is the smell likened to it? Or is there another meaning here that I cannot figure out?

Comment: This feels very idiosyncratic to me. It could be that the writer was going for something she thought would communicate wonderfully, but failed to pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard the phrase "breaking lather".

One definition of "lather" is foam formed from profuse sweating. I think there's a missing hyphen, so it should have been *mountain-breaking lather*, meaning a sweat whose odor is so extreme that it could cause a mountain to crumble.

Of course, this is meant hyperbolically.

Comment: "Lather" is the foam that collects on the skin of an animal when it exercises to extreme.  "Breaking lather" is something of an idiom for the occurrence of this phenomenon.  The reference is to a gigantic animal ("mountain") breaking lather.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=SMB2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22breaking+lather%22+horse&source=bl&ots=b4Q5dzRzec&sig=ACfU3U21TF8HkmcF6dNFC_Fvbj9JOsI7Lw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs6M6W4ZrmAhUVqZ4KHTiUDkUQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22breaking%20lather%22%20horse&f=false